# Exporting nested list to multiple sheets in the same excel?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, export-to-excel

I have the following nested for loop; that creates a nested list with two levels. This first level is "Scenario" and the second level is "pz". In total there are 30 datasets in the list. How to I export each dataset to a sheet within the same excel workbook?

`pzs <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

`scenarios <- c("Scenario 1","Scenario 2","Scenario 3","Scenario 4","Scenario 5","Scenario 6")`

```
  for(j in scenarios){
    for(i in pzs){
      #print(j)
      #print(i)
  top_20[[i]][[j]] <-   data %>% 
                        filter(scenario == j) %>%
                        filter(i == pz) %>%
                      
                         arrange(desc(Sales)) %>%
                         head(n=10)

    as_Workbook(top_20[[j]][[i]], Workbook = wb, sheet= paste0("run_", i, "_",j))
                    
    }
  }

  top_20
```

Comment: the package `openxlsx` has options that should work well.  Otherwise - what aspect of this are you struggling with?  Is it the nested structure or something else?

Comment: I added a snippet of code in the loop using openxlsx, but receive the following error: Error in UseMethod("as_Workbook") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_Workbook' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
Error in lapply(args, .listify) : reached elapsed time limit

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624520/how-to-export-a-complex-r-list-with-embedded-matrixes-into-xls

Answer (score 0):

You need to add worksheets before you can write to them:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()

for(j in scenarios){
    for(i in pzs){
      #print(j)
      #print(i)
  top_20[[i]][[j]] <-   data %>% 
                        filter(scenario == j) %>%
                        filter(i == pz) %>%
                      
                         arrange(desc(Sales)) %>%
                         head(n=10)

    addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = paste0("run_", i, "_",j))
    writeData(
       wb = wb,
       sheet = paste0("run_", i, "_",j)
       x = top_20[[j]][[i]]
    )
                   
    }
  }

  top_20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using any loops. It uses functions from the `dplyr`, `purrr` and `writexl` packages:

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  mutate(sheet_name = paste0("run_", pz, "_", scenario)) |>
  slice_max(Sales, n = 10, by = sheet_name) |>
  split(~ sheet_name) |>
  purrr::map(~ select(.x, -sheet_name)) |>
  writexl::write_xlsx("output.xlsx")
```

**How it works**

Rather than creating a nested loop we create a named list of 30 elements.

1. From the data we create the sheet names that we will subsequently group by to get the top 10 `Sales`.
2. `slice_max` will get the top 10 highest `Sales` by each combination of `pz` and `scenario`.
3. `split` will split your data frame into a named list of data frames. These data frames will contain the top 10 `Sales`.
4. We iterate over this list to remove the `sheet_name` to clean up the output.
5. `write_xlsx` will automatically write a list of data frames to a workbook. Each list element will be written to its own sheet and the sheet name will be derived from the element name.

---

You could do something similar with your code:

```
top_20 <- list()

for(j in scenarios){
  for(i in pzs){
    sheet_name <- paste0("run_", i, "_",j)
    top_20[[sheet_name]] <-   data %>% 
      filter(scenario == j, pz == i) %>%
      slice_max(Sales, n = 10)
  }
}

writexl::write_xlsx(top_20, "output.xlsx")
```

Generally, it is more efficient to initialize an empty list, but if you do not have many combinations of `pz` and `scenario` then you will not notice much of a difference.

---

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
data <- tidyr::expand_grid(pzs, scenarios) |> 
  dplyr::rename(pz = pzs, scenario = scenarios) |>
  dplyr::mutate(Sales = list(rpois(100, 50))) |>
  tidyr::unnest_longer(Sales)
```